# Data Factory Dynamic Expression using CRM 365 FetchXML

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to convert this dynamic expression in ADF

```
<fetch mapping="logical" version="1.0">
  <entity name="account">
    <attribute name="createdon" />
    <filter>
      <condition attribute="createdon" operator="ge" value="2020-10-20T00:00:00Z" />
      <condition attribute="createdon" operator="le" value="2020-10-20T23:59:59Z" />
    </filter>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

Replacing the Date with a variable or possibly a parameter, if someone can help with this please on how he expression should look like ?

Thank you

Comment: Create variables in ADF pipeline. Replace the date value in the script as `@{variable('variable_name')}`

Comment: Thank you for getting back, just a question, I am trying to create the variable but there is no option for  datetime, just string, bool and array.  Do I have to convert it in the dynamic expressions as I am getting the following error " The expected token is '"' or '''. Line 5, position 60." - Thank you

Comment: 1. When you give value for the variable, give it within double quotes or single quotes. 2. Otherwise in the expression, give `value="@{variable('variable_name')}"`

Answer (score 0):

Replace the date value in the script as `@{variable('variable_name')}` . I tried to repro this. Two variables date1 and date2 of string type are created in ADF and assigned default value. Value should be given within single quotes or double quotes.

[image]

`@{variable('variable_name')}`  is inserted into the expression and the expression looks as in below snippet.

**Query**

```html
<filter>
<condition attribute="createdon" operator="ge" value=@{variables('date1')} />
<condition attribute="createdon" operator="le" value=@{variables('date2')} />
</filter>
```

Instead of giving the value for the variable within quotes,
`@{variables('date1')}` can be wrapped within quotes like `"@{variables('date1')}"`.

This way, variables can be used in dynamic expression in ADF.